# Iterate through list of dictionaries that don't contain the same keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I am struggling when trying to iterate through a large list of dictionaries. For the most part they contain the same keys, but there are a few that are missing some keys. Obviously this causes error and I'm unable to successfully run. Below is a sample of the list:

```
test_dict = [{'away': {'gamesPlayed': 0,
  'pointsByScoringPeriod': {'14': 84.54},
  'teamId': 9,
  'tiebreak': 0.0,
  'totalPoints': 84.54},
'home': {'gamesPlayed': 0,
  'pointsByScoringPeriod': {'14': 84.54},
  'teamId': 9,
  'tiebreak': 0.0,
  'totalPoints': 84.54},
'id': 98,
'matchupPeriodId': 14,
'playoffTierType': 'NONE',
'winner': 'AWAY'},
{'home': {'gamesPlayed': 0,
  'pointsByScoringPeriod': {'14': 84.54},
  'teamId': 9,
  'tiebreak': 0.0,
  'totalPoints': 84.54},
'id': 98,
'matchupPeriodId': 14,
'playoffTierType': 'NONE',
'winner': 'AWAY'}]
```

We are missing `away` in the second dictionary, so when I run the following code:

```
matchup_data = []
for matchup in test_dict:
    Week = matchup['matchupPeriodId']
    Matchup_ID = matchup['id']
    Winner = matchup['winner']
    Game_Type = matchup['playoffTierType']
    Away_ID = matchup['away']['teamId']
    Away_Points = matchup['away']['totalPoints']
    Home_ID = matchup['home']['teamId']
    Home_Points = matchup['home']['totalPoints']
    matchup_data.append([
                Week, Matchup_ID, Winner, Game_Type, Away_ID, Away_Points, Home_ID, Home_Points
    ])
```

I obviously get the error `KeyError: 'away'` since `away` is nowhere to be found in the second dictionary.

Is there a way to ignore the missing keys and just put a `NULL` in place of the variables for the dictionaries where `away` is missing? Thank you in advance.

Finally, if this has already been asked I apologize as I cannot seem to find it anywhere. I see multiple questions regarding iterating through dictionaries but none regarding different keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
matchup['away']['teamId']
```

with:

```
matchup['away']['teamId'] if 'away' in matchup else None
```

You can also use chained calls to `.get`, with each call supplying an appropriate default:

```
matchup.get('away', {}).get('teamId', None)
```

Comment: Terrific, thank you so much! Is one of those more efficient/preferred than the other?

Comment: Matter of taste.  I find the first one a little easier to read.